# Snowflake SQL: Need a Date Spine added to Existing Table Columns

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have two separate tables.
Table1 contains only 1 column, called date_spine and it has all dates from 2021-01-01 to current date.
Table2 contains distinct columns of State, Store.
My final goal is to create a new Table which contains all Dates in the Data Spine against every unique State, Store combination.  Below is a brief example.  I am hoping for SQL Script which will work in Snowflake.  Thank you in advance!!

| State | Store | Date_Spine |
| --- | --- | --- |
| IL | Chicago | 2021-01-01 |
| IL | Chicago | 2021-01-02 |
| IL | Chicago | 2021-01-03 |
| IL | Chicago | 2021-01-04 |
| IL | Chicago | 2021-01-05 |
| MO | St Louis | 2021-01-01 |
| MO | St Louis | 2021-01-02 |
| MO | St Louis | 2021-01-03 |
| MO | St Louis | 2021-01-04 |
| MO | St Louis | 2021-01-05 |

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use a cross join approach with calendar tables:

```sql
SELECT t1.Date_Spine, t2.State, t2.Store
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT Date_Spine FROM Table1) t1
CROSS JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT State, Store FROM Table2) t2
ORDER BY t2.State, t2.Store, t1.Date_Spine;
```